# is there a good way to import .json file content using .sql script file?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

we have SQL project in Visual Studio with several .sql script files in it to populate data to Microsoft SQL Server.
some .sql scripts import JSON data, which now is defined as a raw string inside sql files. I was thinking on extracting JSONs to separate files. What I found is examples like this

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '**C:\**sampledata.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) as importData
```

but they all have full path to source file, which is ridiculous and probably fail if run on another machine with different folder structure.
Is there a way to embed .json files into SQL project and reference them from .sql file in more flexible way, to guarantee that compiled script will work?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this myself, and I don't think it'll work.

- The `OPENROWSET BULK` method of reading data from a file only accepts a full path.

  - You could try and get around this with a pre/post-deployment script and some SQLCMD variables, but then you run into the next issue.
- `OPENROWSET` will only work if the file can be accessed from the machine running the query. If you run this against a remote server, you'll have to jump through some hoops to give it access to your data file.
- Also, if you want to do this from an Azure SQL database, you'll need to store the data in Azure Blob Storage.

[OPENROWSET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Here's the best recommendation I can provide. Assuming that your primary goals are to a) ensure legibility in the code and b) allow for a more clear diff when updating the JSON data, create separate scalar-valued functions for each of your JSON strings. Each function will simply return your raw JSON string. Not exactly creative, but it will allow you to format your JSON for maximum legibility while allowing you to clean up the scripts that actually use this data.

e.g. Instead of having one file that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"attr":"value 1"},{"attr":"value 2"},{"attr":"value 3"},{"attr":"value 4"},{"attr":"value 5"},{"attr":"value 6"},{"attr":"value 7"},{"attr":"value 8"},{"attr":"value 9"},{"attr":"value 10"}]'
--do stuff with the @json
```

Have two files, one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetJson()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN N'
[
  {
    "attr": "value 1"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 2"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 3"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 4"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 5"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 6"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 7"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 8"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 9"
  },
  {
    "attr": "value 10"
  }
]
'
END
```

and two:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = dbo.GetJson()
--do stuff with @json
```

Comment: oof, not exactly what I want, but thanks for suggestion anyways. The main issue is still JSON not being in .json file, so when you edit the thing, you edit a string in .sql file, not .json file...

Comment: I suppose the other way would be to set up some sort of pre-build script to properly handle single quotes in your .json file and insert the result into your .sql file before the .dacpac is generated.